# How to configure two datasources in spring batch 5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-batch

How can we leverage @EnableBatchProcessing and extend default Configuration to use two data sources in Spring batch 5?

Is the best practice much different than the previous version of spring batch?

Comment: What do yo mean by two datasources? Spring Batch requires a single datasource for the job repository. Please share a code example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Inject your two datasources into your configuration class using @Autowired annotation.

Define then a job that consists of two steps, each using a different datasource. Use the step() method to create a step for each data source, and pass the appropriate datasource as a parameter. Inside each step, define a reader, processor, and writer that use the corresponding data source. For example: read from datasource1 and write to datasource2.

You can configure your datasources separately, either in your application.properties file or in a separate configuration class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample implementation.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.ds1.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@{host}:{port}:{database}
spring.datasource.ds1.username={username}
spring.datasource.ds1.password={password}
spring.datasource.ds1.hikari.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.ds1.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.ds1.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
spring.datasource.ds1.hikari.connection-timeout=120000
spring.datasource.ds1.hikari.idle-timeout=120000
spring.datasource.ds1.hikari.max-lifetime=300000
spring.datasource.ds1.hikari.pool-name=HikariPool-1
#
spring.datasource.ds2.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@{host}:{port}:{database}
spring.datasource.ds2.username={username}
spring.datasource.ds2.password={password}
spring.datasource.ds2.hikari.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.ds2.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.ds2.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
spring.datasource.ds2.hikari.connection-timeout=120000
spring.datasource.ds2.hikari.idle-timeout=120000
spring.datasource.ds2.hikari.max-lifetime=300000
spring.datasource.ds2.hikari.pool-name=HikariPool-2
```

**configuration.java**

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AppConfiguration {


    // == Datasource Configuration ==
    @Bean(name = "ds1DataSourceProperties")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.ds1")
    public DataSourceProperties ds1DataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ds1DataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.ds1.hikari")
    public HikariDataSource ds1DataSource(@Qualifier("ds1DataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties ds1DataSourceProperties) {
        return ds1DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ds1JdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate ds1JdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("ds1DataSource") HikariDataSource ds1DataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds1DataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "ds2DataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.w")
    public DataSourceProperties ds2DataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ds2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.w.hikari")
    public HikariDataSource ds2DataSource(@Qualifier("ds2DataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties ds2DataSourceProperties) {
        return ds2DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ds2JdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate ds2JdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("ds2DataSource") HikariDataSource ds2DataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds2DataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "ccbsWriteTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager ccbsWriteTransactionManager(@Qualifier("ds2DataSource") HikariDataSource ds2DataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(ds2DataSource);
    }
```

you can define the relevant datasource in your reader, processor, and writer.

Comment: i am not able to find how we can set data source with reader or processor. There is no option in spring 5. Can u please post an example.